# How to show all data with Teamwork API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show all data task in the Teamwork API, but Teamwork just shows 250 data tasks per page. I've tried using a `while` statement, but this results in an infinite loop.

I expect the output, if all task all has gone out so the params page does not do increment again

```js
$(function() {
  let tasks;
  while (tasks) {
    url = '/data.json?page=' + page++
    $.ajax(url, {
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data['todo-items'], function(key, task) {
          tasks = data['todo-items'].length
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: while (tasks) is always true in your function, you are not setting it to false when all are done. hope this helps. Ajax calls are asynchronous by nature and defaults to true

Comment: Try async#whilst: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#whilst. Essentially it will call the API over and over again until no more responses are returned, then it will call the final callback

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP Header. The total number of items is in the X-Records HTTP header.

There are 3 different headers associated with paging for the projects API. If you go to the developer tools in your browser, and do a ‘GET’ call. You will see in the headers section if you inspect the browser. There is 3 header values:

X-Page - the current page being returned
X-Pages - the total number of pages available
X-Records - the total number of items available

You can request a specific page by calling the same API call and adding the parameter &page=n where n is the page you want. e.g: &page=2 for page 2, &page=5 for page 5.

See more at https://developer.teamwork.com/projects/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/how-does-paging-work

Here is a PHP function that we used to loop the results

```
   /**
 * NOTE: Can only pull 500 at a time. see docs, after that must pull pages
 * By default, pulls all active projects, ordered by project name, includes custom fields.
 *
 * @link https://developer.teamwork.com/projects/api-v2/ref/custom-fields/getprojectsapiv2projectsjson
 * @example https://deltasystemsgroup.teamwork.com/projects/api/v2/projects.json?includeCustomFields=true
 * @param none
 * @return array of entire response. you'll want to pull off $responseData['projects'] and $responseData['customFields']
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getAllProjectsRaw()
{
    // DO NOT USE V1 - no custom fields - https://developer.teamwork.com/projects/api-v1/ref/projects/get-projects-json

    $page = 0;
    $pageSize = 500;

    $all_projects = [];
    $all_custom_fields = []; //for each project

    do {
        $page++;

        $response = $this->makeApiRequest("/projects/api/v2/projects.json",
            [
                'query' => [
                    'includeCustomFields' => 'true',
                    'page' => "{$page}",
                    'pageSize' => "{$pageSize}"
                ],
            ]
        );

        $responseData = json_decode(
            $response->getBody(), true);

        if (!$responseData) {
            throw new Exception('Page ' . $page . ' : Failed to decode Teamwork time entry API response as JSON');
        }

        if (!isset($responseData['STATUS'])) {
            throw new Exception('Page ' . $page . ' : Teamwork time entry API response did not include STATUS');
        }

        if ('OK' !== $responseData['STATUS']) {
            throw new Exception('Page ' . $page . ' : Teamwork time entry API response did not respond with
           STATUS = OK. Status response was: ' . $responseData['STATUS']);
        }

        if (1== $page) {
            $all_custom_fields = array_merge($all_custom_fields, $responseData['customFields']);
        }
        $all_projects = array_merge($all_projects, $responseData['projects']);

        //The total number of projects is in the X-Records HTTP header.
        // X-Pages will be set to the total number of pages, and X-Page will be set to the current page.
        //so we added a loop
        $xPages = -1;
        if ($response->getHeader('X-Pages')[0]) {
            $xPages = (int)$response->getHeader('X-Pages')[0];
        }
    } while ($page < $xPages);

    $custom_fields_and_all_projects['customFields'] = $all_custom_fields;
    $custom_fields_and_all_projects['projects'] = $all_projects;

    return $custom_fields_and_all_projects;
}
```